# Derivative of a particular logarithmic function

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

I have a vector $\mathbf{x} = [x_1 \,\, x_2 \,\, x_3] \in \mathbb{R}^3$, and a function $f\left(\mathbf{x} \right) = \log\left(x_1 - 3x_2^2 + 5x_3^2 \right)$.

What is the derivative of $f\left(\mathbf{x} \right)$ w.r.t. $\mathbf{x}$? Do I have to perform the derivative w.r.t. $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ at the same time? For example, is it correct to calculate it as below?

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \, f\left(\mathbf{x} \right)}{\partial \, \mathbf{x}} = \frac{1 - 6x_2 + 10x_3}{x_1 - 3x_2^2 + 5x_3^2}\,.
\end{equation}

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Look up the gradient and partial differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you have

$$f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = \ln(x_1 - 3x_2^2 + 5x_3^2)$$

Which is a function in three variables. When it comes to take the derivative of this function wrt $x_1, x_2, x_3$ the gradient comes into play

[Gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient)

$$\nabla f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_!} \hat{i} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} \hat{j} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3} \hat{k}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} = \frac{1}{x_1 - 3x_2^2 + 5x_3^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = -\frac{6x_2}{x_1 - 3x_2^2 + 5x_3^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3} = \frac{10x_3}{x_1 - 3x_2^2 + 5x_3^2}$$

Comment: Thank you so much.